# MPMoviePlayerController How pause .mov at specific breakpoints?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nstimer, playback, nsnotifications

I need to play a .mov inside my ios 6 app.

**Do you know how can I handle to pause and stop it given specific time breakpoints?**

I tried with a **NSTimer** that fires every x seconds a checkCurrentPlabackTime Action that checks against a list of breakpoints..

But its not accurate!
sometimes it doesnt stop where I want.. some other doesnt stop at all

```
#define kTimer 0.01
#define kAccuracy 0.01

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [..]

 pauseTimeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.00]  ,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00] ,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.30] ,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16.00] ,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:18.80] ,
                  nil];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kTimer 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(timeAction) 
                               userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timeAction{


// Check next breakpoint find the difference with the actual (Es. 02:00 - 00:00) -> I need you to stop again in 2 seconds



if (self.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {

 //self.player is my mpMoviePlayerController instance
    NSNumber * positionNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.player.currentPlaybackTime];

    float positionFloat = [positionNum floatValue];
    NSLog(@"positionFloat:%f",positionFloat);

    for (NSNumber * pauseNum in pauseTimeArray) {

        float pauseFloat = [pauseNum floatValue];

        float differentFloat = fabsf(pauseFloat - positionFloat);

        if (differentFloat < kAccuracy) {
            [self.player pause];

           NSDictionary * dicInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:pauseNum,@"pauseIndex", nil];
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                            postNotificationName:LSMoviePlayerPlaybackDidPauseNotification
                                          object:self
                                        userInfo:dicInfo];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My assumption for the breakpoint not firing at all: The given accuracy might be a bit too tight, 0.01 means that you expect the timer to fire at the accuracy of a 100th second, a regular timer will most certainly not match that as it runs in the main loop.

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
double loadTime =moviePlayerController.playableDuration;
double currentTime =moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
double totalTime =moviePlayerController.duration;
```

you can pause your `MPMoviewplayercontroller` in particular time using current time

Comment: How would that help as the OP clearly uses currentPlaybackTime already.